# NodeJS Read ASCII from Buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have an application that will receive a file with the binary format `<type>:<location>\n<binary>`, so a picture may look like `image:~/documents/image.png\n<image>`.

To read this in node, I have the following code.

```
var type = '';
var destination = '';
var i = -1;

while (data[++i] != ':')
    type += data[i];

while (data[++i] != '\n')
    destination += data[i];

data = data.slice(i);
```

However, this causes Node to eat up all the RAM and CPU, and eventually crash. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
var type = '';
var destination = '';
var char = '';
var i = 0;

while ((char = String.fromCharCode(data.readUInt8(i++))) != ':')
    type += char;

while ((char = String.fromCharCode(data.readUInt8(i++))) != '\n')
    destination += char;

data = data.slice(i);
```